# How to access chrome.runtime from svelte project

Tags: firefox-addon, svelte, browser-extension, webextension-polyfill

I am building a svelte browser extension, and in order to load images, I found out that I can use `chrome.runtime.getURL(relative_path)`, which is well supported across browsers.

So, I wrote this code:

```html
  <img
    src={chrome.runtime.getURL("image.png")}
    alt={"an image"}
  />
```

When trying to build, I get:

```bash
transforming (8) node_modules/.pnpm/svelte@3.55.1/node_modules/svelte/transition/ind13:09:26 [vite-plugin-svelte] /MyComponent.svelte:17:9 'chrome' is not defined
15: <button on:click={handleOnClick}>
16:   <img
17:     src={chrome.runtime.getURL("image.png")}
             ^
18:     alt={"an image"}
19:   />
✓ 25 modules transformed.
```

I tried to polyfill this using `webextension-polyfill` and `@types/chrome` npm packages with no success.

**My workaround**:

I created this function

```js
  const polifillImg = (img: string) => {
    // At build time this will be replaced by chrome.runtime.getURL(imgSrcBase + img)
    return (
      "__REPLACE_WITH_CHROME__" + imgSrcBase + img + "__CLOSING_PARENTESIS__"
    );
  };
```

Which I can now use like so:

```html
  <img
    src={polifillImg("image.png")}
    alt={"an image"}
  />
```

And in my `vite.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";
import { replaceCodePlugin } from "vite-plugin-replace";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    replaceCodePlugin({
      replacements: [
        { from: '"__REPLACE_WITH_CHROME__" + ', to: "chrome.runtime.getURL(" },
        { from: ' + "__CLOSING_PARENTESIS__"', to: ")" },
      ],
    }),
    svelte(),
  ],
});
```

Which, you know, works, but it is not great.

I would like to know how to correctly use the `chrome` object the right way. Can someone show me the way?

Thanks